# Accessing SCORM sitting in ec2 instance from a Application server

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, remote-access, scorm

I need to access a SCORM content through my application (LMS). Now, this content is stored in the filesystem in a different AWS ec2 instance (ubuntu machine).

My server has different application instances installed for serving different clients. Each client instance has a separate filesystem repo sitting on a same ec2 server.

How do I maintain that the SCORM opened by a specific user interacts only with the specific client application instance so that SCORM interaction parameter values get saved in the correct database?

Note : My application does not have a multitenant architecture.

Sorry for a such a generic question, actually I am a little confused hence a little direction would be appreciated so that further I can find my way out.

Answer (score 0):

SCORM and Cross Domain would require some work.  If you can get the content and the Platform on the same domain that would go easier.  Another option would be to just get all the content files to point to their CSS/JS/IMG assets on the other server.  Then your playing in the right sandbox.

Short of that there are some IFRAME hacks out there to do the same but it pretty much requires you to touch things that would lend it self to just pointing to all the Assets anyway without the go-between.

SCORM is a JavaScript<->JavaScript communication.  The LMS will send the data stored in a session to the backend commonly on a commit call.